# Specify alternate JSONpaths

Tags: apache-nifi, jsonpath

Suppose I have one JSON log that outputs the following information:

```
{"timestamp":"someText","alert":"someMoreText","Level":someInt}
```

And I have another JSON log that outputs the same kind of information but with different label's:

```
{"ts":"someText","alert":"someMoreText","Level":someInt}
```

The difference being *"timestamp"* and *"ts"* have different names yet same quality information. **How would I reference, with one JSON path call, either one of the alternate names, if such a technique is possible?**

So for example, if I wanted it to reference the timestamp of both logs, I would want to use something like `$.[timestamp|ts]`

Comment: evaluate them separately and then use `ifElse` in expression language https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#ifelse

Comment: @daggett This is valid, but this is inefficient for the current scope. The aim was to optimize upon this by not having to use the Update Attribute Processor. NiFi expressions are not supported in the EvaluateJSONPath Processor as of NiFi 1.3.0 and I wanted to see if I could circumvent the issue of it via this question.

Comment: i don't see in jsonpath documentation such possibility. if you want to minimize processors count, use executescript processor with groovy or javascript. both have good functionality to work with json.

Comment: Sounds good. Ill be sure to work on developing that to see if I can reduce the processors count.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new record processors, you might be able to do something like...

- Define a schema that has both 'timestamp' and 'ts'
- Send all the records with 'ts' to an UpdateRecord processor
- Set the UpdateRecord processor to make /timestamp = /ts
- Define another version of the schema that doesn't have 'ts'
- Use a ConvertRecord processor with a writer that uses the second schema

That last step would rewrite the records without the 'ts' field.

Alternatively, you could try defining a schema with a 'timestamp' field and an alias of 'ts' which should let any of the record processors access both fields by using 'timestamp'. It would depend what you are doing in your flow to see if it can be achieved with the record processors.

Comment: Would this take about 3 processors?

Comment: Yes most likely

Comment: My current setup eliminates the need for an updateRecord and convertRecord processor thanks to some clever routing and additional specifications from the JSONpath processor. I do not doubt this is a valid option, but I would have to see how efficient it is compared to my current setup.